# Liquibase diff data between 2 DB's

Tags: liquibase

We are planning to use liquibase to maintain some reference data (dataset is less than 20K rows). Data would be updated and validated in QC env and we want to move the changes to prod, using liquibase.

I used generateChangeLog with diffTypes=data

During the first pass it generated the changeLog with insert statements.

Now I go and add a new row and update one of the existing row & rerun the command. I was hoping it would generate 1 insert and 1 update statement, but it ended up generating only insert statements, which included all the original insert statements.

Is there a way to generate changelog with only rows that were changed/added/removed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no.